# SQL grouping results by first date of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Currently writing an sql query on sql server 2008 and have a query which counts the amount of sales in a week, currently my code is grouping by week number however I am wanting to return the first date in the week.

currently it's returning

```
week number count
1             5
2             3
3             8
```

what I'm trying to get it to do is

```
Week Number Date Count
1     1/01/2015    5
2     7/01/2015    3
3     14/01/2015   8
```

Currently the code I have is

```
SELECT DATEPART(WK,CAST(a.sale_date AS DATE)), count(a.sale)
from sales a
where a.sale_date >= Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(Day, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, -52, current_timestamp)), 0)
group by DATEPART(WK,CAST(a.sale_date AS DATE))
```

Any time I try and add the sale_date column it prints out similar to the following

```
Week Date count
1  1/01/2015 2
1  2/01/2015 1
1  5/01/2015 2
2  7/01/2015 1
2  7/01/2015 2
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/how-do-you-get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql).  In summary, you need to get the current day of week from the date and then subtract a number of days in order to get the first day of the week, like so:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WK,CAST(a.sale_date AS DATE)), 
max(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, a.sale_date) - 1), a.sale_date)) as WeekStart, sum(1) as Count 
from testdata a
where a.sale_date >= Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(Day, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, -52, current_timestamp)), 0)
group by DATEPART(WK,CAST(a.sale_date AS DATE));
```

Edit: Notice how you used count instead of sum, this was your main issue as count counts all distinct values, whereas sum just gives you a sum of rows in that grouping.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c294/2)

Comment: Hi when I implement the code above I receive the same error message as earlier

Comment: I see.  And what is that error message?  I don't see anything about an error message in your question

Comment: Error message was a poor word choice, apologies.

It is printing out multiple dates for week 1/week2/week3 similar to the last example in the o.p

Comment: Yes, sorry, there's an error in your original SQL I missed.  You don't want to use count, but rather sum to get a total of the values.  I have updated my answer, please mark it right if I helped you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are heading in the right direction, I think you would just need to go a little further after you add the `sale_date` column to your query and do something like this:

```
SELECT t.WEEK_NUMBER
    ,MIN(t.Sale_date) OVER (
        PARTITION BY t.WEEK_NUMBER ORDER BY t.WEEK_NUMBER
        ) as Week_StartDate
    ,SUM(t.Amount_of_Sales_Count) Amount_of_Sales_Total_Count
FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(week, CAST(a.sale_date AS DATE)) Week_Number
        ,sale_date
        ,count(a.sale) Amount_of_Sales_Count
    FROM sales a
    WHERE a.sale_date >= 
              Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(Day, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, - 52, current_timestamp)), 0)
        GROUP BY DATEPART(WK, CAST(a.sale_date AS DATE))
            ,sale_date
        ) t
    GROUP BY t.WEEK_NUMBER
```