# create a column using sql that shows first day of the week and last day of the week

Tags: mysql, sql, format

Trying to create a column that will tell me the weekofyear() as well as the dates:

```
Week  Date                       org   cost
--------------------------------------------
50    "2016/12/12-2016/12/18"    1     400
51    "2016/12/19-2016/12/25"    1     400
52    "2016/12/26"               1     400
```

So this tells me that Week 52 only includes data from the December 26th and not for the whole week.

here is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    weekofyear(date) as week_number,
    exchange,
    country,
    channel,
    sum (media_cost) as mc 
FROM 
    imps
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN '2016-12-26' AND '2017-01-08'
GROUP BY
    weekofyear(date) as week_number,
    exchange,
    country,
    channel;
```

I have looked at [How do you get the “week start date” and “week end date” from week number in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/how-do-you-get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql) but this won't solve the issue of seeing what days it does include. 
Would using bins work for this maybe? What are your suggestions.

Comment: It's very hard to understand a question with so little information. Please provide some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Really don't know what you are asking for, but the strtotime function in PHP can convert a week number into a date like this: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2017W01"));`. That will give you the first date in the first week of 2017.

Comment: @CptMisery tried to make the question more clear

Comment: @Mureinik have added more data and sample result

Answer (score 0):

In your query, that `WHERE` will not work because the string "2016/12/12-2016/12/18" will never be between two dates. You would need to make two date columns such as `week_begin` and `week_end`. Then your `WHERE` could be:

```
WHERE week_begin BETWEEN '2016-12-26' AND '2017-01-08'
   OR week_end BETWEEN '2016-12-26' AND '2017-01-08'
```