# Showing week dates ranges as a part of select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to fetch the count on a daily basis where the startdate and enddate are parameters passed from the application and I used a sample dates here to demonstrate the query

```
SELECT  
    CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) AS Date, 
    COUNT(0) AS Total  
FROM 
    SessionTable
WHERE  
    DateCreated >= '10/02/2015'  
    AND CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) <= '10/30/2015' 
GROUP BY
    CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) 
ORDER BY
    CAST(DateCreated AS DATE)
```

This will return the result in format

```
Date Total
```

Now I decided to reduce the number of records by converting date-wise count to week-wise count and I use the query

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(wk, DateCreated) AS WeekNumber, 
    COUNT(0) AS WeekCount 
FROM 
    SessionTable
WHERE  
    DateCreated >= '10/02/2015'  
    AND CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) <= '10/30/2015' 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)
```

This returns the result in the format  and is working fine

```
WeekNumber  WeekCount
-------------------------
  40           2298
  41          13998
  42          19454
  43          19923
```

To make the result set more clear i am planning to add the begin date and end date of each week as well to the above result set , but struggled to do so

My expected result is

```
    WeekNumber BeginDate  EndDate WeekCount
```

To fetch the weekBegin and End Date [How do you get the "week start date" and "week end date" from week number in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126) suggestion from this can be used and i written the query like

```
         SELECT 
    DATEPART(wk, DateCreated) AS WeekNumber, 
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, DateCreated)-1), DateCreated) as [WeekStart],
    DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DateCreated)), DateCreated)  as [WeekEnd],
    COUNT(0) AS WeekCount 
    FROM 
    Session
    WHERE  
    DateCreated >= '10/02/2015'  
    AND CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) <= '10/30/2015' 
    GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(wk, DateCreated),
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, DateCreated)-1), DateCreated),
    DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DateCreated)), DateCreated)
```

But this returned my resultset with a count as 1 for each day something like below

```
    WeekNumber  WeekStart       WeekEnd                     WeekCount
    44  2015-10-25 18:02:26.527 2015-10-31 18:02:26.527 1
    44  2015-10-25 10:53:16.057 2015-10-31 10:53:16.057 1
    42  2015-10-11 11:23:57.253 2015-10-17 11:23:57.253 1
    40  2015-09-27 09:04:39.063 2015-10-03 09:04:39.063 1
    44  2015-10-25 10:44:38.573 2015-10-31 10:44:38.573 1
    44  2015-10-25 14:33:31.803 2015-10-31 14:33:31.803 1
    44  2015-10-25 08:18:28.020 2015-10-31 08:18:28.020 1
    44  2015-10-25 12:19:21.270 2015-10-31 12:19:21.270 1
```

So how can I add `BeginDate` and `EndDate` values to each row from query correctly?

Comment: Take a look here, there are several solutions to this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/how-do-you-get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the "week start date" and "week end date" from week number in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/how-do-you-get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql)

Comment: @Egbert The given thread is helpful to get an answer on how to add StarDate and Enddate of weeks , but  i am struggling to integrate them with count queries and thats why i have raised question

Comment: @Egbert i have edited my question with proper issues i am facing now. So please help to remove duplicate status if possible

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(wk, DateCreated) AS WeekNumber, 
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + year(datecreated)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 6) AS StartOfWeek,
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + year(datecreated)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 5) AS EndOfWeek
COUNT(0) AS WeekCount 
FROM 
SessionTable
WHERE  
DateCreated >= '10/02/2015'  
AND CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) <= '10/30/2015' 
GROUP BY 
DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)
```

**Correction**:

You should convert the startofweek and endofweek to date datatype and then add the same in the group by clause. The same is as follows:

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(wk, DateCreated) AS WeekNumber, 
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + year(datecreated)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 6) AS DATE) AS StartOfWeek,
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + year(datecreated)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 5) AS DATE)  AS EndOfWeek
COUNT(0) AS WeekCount 
FROM SessionTable
WHERE DateCreated >= '10/02/2015' AND CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) <= '10/30/2015' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, DateCreated),
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + year(datecreated)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 6) AS DATE),
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + year(datecreated)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 5) AS DATE)
```

**Update 2:**

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(wk, DateCreated) AS WeekNumber, 
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + cast(year(datecreated) as varchar)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 6) AS DATE) AS StartOfWeek,
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + cast(year(datecreated) as varchar)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 5) AS DATE)  AS EndOfWeek
COUNT(0) AS WeekCount 
FROM SessionTable
WHERE DateCreated >= '10/02/2015' AND CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) <= '10/30/2015' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, DateCreated),
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + cast(year(datecreated) as varchar)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 6) AS DATE),
CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + cast(year(datecreated) as varchar)) + (DATEPART(wk, DateCreated)-1), 5) AS DATE)
```

This should work now.

Comment: will get a syntax error saying thart Column '.DateCreated' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Now issue is Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1/1/' to data type int. BTWN any suggestions as per my edit on question

Comment: After some research of my own and based on recommendations from answers and comments in this thread now i am getting week start date and end date. 
But i can see 3 different approaches  [https://pastebin.com/pviVj3UM] . Anyone can explain which will works best way in all scenarios like date in the beggining of year etc

Answer (score 1):

If you modifiy your query like this, you should get the desired results.
The problem was that you grouped by DateCreated including the time. The Cast to Date solves this problem.

```
    SELECT 
    DATEPART(wk, DateCreated) AS WeekNumber, 
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, CAST(DateCreated AS Date))-1), CAST(DateCreated AS Date)) as [WeekStart],
    DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, CAST(DateCreated AS Date))), CAST(DateCreated AS Date))  as [WeekEnd],
    COUNT(0) AS WeekCount 
    FROM 
    Session
    WHERE  
    DateCreated >= '10/02/2015'  
    AND CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) <= '10/30/2015' 
    GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(wk, DateCreated),
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, CAST(DateCreated AS Date))-1), CAST(DateCreated AS Date)),
    DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, CAST(DateCreated AS Date))), CAST(DateCreated AS Date))
```

Comment: After some research of my own and based on recommendations from answers and comments in this thread now i am getting week start date and end date. 
But i can see 3 different approaches  [https://pastebin.com/pviVj3UM] . Anyone can explain which will works best way in all scenarios like date in the beggining of year etc

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to implement in sql.But you can try this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
    .Select(i => "DateTime")
    .ToArray()
```