# Need some DateDiff calculating a week starting on Monday

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL. I tried to use to calculate the date for the beginning of the week. I need my week to start on Monday:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Monday (First Week day)

DECLARE @dt DATETIME2

SELECT DATEADD(week, (-1) * (datepart(dw, @dt) - 1), @dt) AS datetime2--(7)

DECLARE @SchDT Datetime
DECLARE @TstPeriod varchar(20)
SET @TstPeriod = 'Week'

IF @TstPeriod = 'Month'
    SET @SchDT = cast(DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()),-1) as datetime2(7))

IF @TstPeriod = 'Week'
    SET @SchDT = cast(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE()),-1) as datetime2(7))

SELECT @SchDT
```

Only after this, I realized that SQL Server considers the beginning of the week to be on Sunday - no matter what.

Has anyone come across a similar need and could share how to make SQL Server calculate `datediff()` using Monday as beginning of the week?

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the "week start date" and "week end date" from week number in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/how-do-you-get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql)

Comment: Tip: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using multiple calls to `GetDate()`, whether in a single statement or multiple statements, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Comment: *I realized that SQL Server considers the beginning of the week to be on Sunday - no matter what.* No, not *no matter what*. This is culture related...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `SET DATEFIRST` (or `SET LANGUAGE`) for the whole batch. This might have various unexpected sideeffects.

There is `@@DATEFIRST`, reflecting the *first day of the week* as `INT` value. Use this to compute your value **independantly**.

--You can check the difference

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT @@DATEFIRST; 
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT @@DATEFIRST;
```

--I set a variable

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME=GETDATE();
```

--Simple computation like suggestion in another answer will return different days depending on the system's culture

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@d)+2,@d);
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@d)+2,@d);
```

--But using `@@DATEFIRST` you can get a correction term into your calculation

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-((DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@d) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7),@d);
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-((DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@d) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7),@d);
```

Comment: Thank you all and thank you Shnugo.  This last one using @@DATEFIRST seems to do exactly what I was looking for and return the date for the Monday of a given week.
I appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Should give you this week's Monday.

This is equivalent to:

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '1900-01-01', GETDATE()), '1900-01-01')
```

Since Jan 1, 1900 was a Monday adding weeks to that date returns future mondays.

---

As Shnugo pointed out, if `getdate()` returns a Sunday this will actually apply to the following Monday. You can use a function to check what day it is and manipulate the date as necessary.

An example using `DATENAME`:

`SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '1900-01-01', CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ELSE GETDATE() END), '1900-01-01')`

Comment: Better answer than mine, I knew that trick for months not sure where my brain went. Looks like OP was very close, just needs to change his -1 to 0 and he'll be fine.

Comment: Yes but I definitely recommend the second form, since it is so much more self-documenting.

Comment: I just compared your solution (which I like a lot) with mine and found them both equally fast. But - by incidence -  I encountered a flaw: Try this `SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '1900-01-01', '2018-04-01'), '1900-01-01')`. On Sundays you'll get the **next** Monday as answer...

Comment: @Zorkolot, well, your edit works. but the solution's elegance somehow disappeared :-D And there is a BIG flaw: This is depending on culture/language. In my environment "Sunday" is "Sonntag"...

Comment: @Zorkolot You might check `sys.syslanguages` and read the `days` with `REVERSE` and `SUBSTRING` with `CHARINDEX`... Okay, I'm joking ;-D

Comment: @Shnugo `SELECT DATEPART(dw, '2018-04-01')` is an alternative, where Sunday = 0.  I used `DATENAME` for clarity, in the end it is syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Zorkolot cannot test this at the moment, but I'm afraid this is culture dependant...

Comment: @Shnugo Very interesting Shnugo!  I've tested and it does change `DATEPART`.

Comment: @Zorkolot, well you might add some correction logic with `@@DATEFIRST` to the return value of `DATEPART(dw,...)`, but this would get rather ugly...

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the monday of the week of your date.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(day,-DATEPART(weekday,@dt)+2,@dt))
```

Comment: Try this with `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;` and `SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;`