# SQL - using calculated dates in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with future values where I only want the last full week.

Meaning af want to find the last Sunday and have a WHERE clause where date is between 'last Sunday - 7' and 'last Sunday'.

Meaning I have transactions until '31-10-2018' and want the period between '2018-10-28' and '2018-10-22' (both days included). But every week new data will be added continuously so very soon I have data until '2018-11-30' and so on.

I have tried a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM PlannedCounts
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-6,MAX([Date])) and MAX([Date])
```

Note: I'm aware that this will only give me last day ('2018-10-31' and not last Sunday).

How can I include calculated dates in my where claus and also conditioning the target date to be last Sunday?

My table have the following columns:

```
Date
Location
Type
Material
Value
Manager
```

[image: Picture of my dataset and expected result]

Comment: Please provide the result set you are looking for.  The question is not clear.

Comment: Is it SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it's and SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given date `2018-10-31` you need to determine the day of week (1 ... 7) so that you can calculate the previous Sunday. Unfortunately it is not straight forward ([see discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267126/87015)):

```
CREATE TABLE #PlannedCounts(Date Date);
INSERT INTO #PlannedCounts(Date) VALUES
    ('2018-10-31'),
    ('2018-10-30'),
    ('2018-10-29'),
    ('2018-10-28'),
    ('2018-10-27'),
    ('2018-10-26'),
    ('2018-10-25'),
    ('2018-10-24'),
    ('2018-10-23'),
    ('2018-10-22'),
    ('2018-10-21'),
    ('2018-10-20'),
    ('2018-10-19'),
    ('2018-10-18'),
    ('2018-10-17'),
    ('2018-10-16'),
    ('2018-10-15'),
    ('2018-10-14'),
    ('2018-10-13'),
    ('2018-10-12');

DECLARE @LastSunday AS DATE;
DECLARE @PrevSunday AS DATE;

SELECT
    @LastSunday = DATEADD(DAY, -(@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, MAX(Date)) - 1) % 7 - 0, MAX(Date)),
    @PrevSunday = DATEADD(DAY, -(@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, MAX(Date)) - 1) % 7 - 6, MAX(Date))
FROM #PlannedCounts

-- @LastSunday = 2018-10-28
-- @PrevSunday = 2018-10-22

SELECT *
FROM #PlannedCounts
WHERE Date BETWEEN @PrevSunday AND @LastSunday
```

Note: it is possible to replace user variables with queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need a case statement in where clause -

```
SELECT *
FROM PlannedCounts
WHERE [Date] >= CASE WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Monday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-1,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Tuesday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-2,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Wednesday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-3,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Thursday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-4,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Friday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-5,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Saturday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-6,MAX([Date]))
                 ELSE MAX([Date] END
AND [Date] <= CASE WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Monday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-7,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Tuesday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-8,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Wednesday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-9,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Thursday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-10,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Friday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-11,MAX([Date]))
                     WHEN DAYNAME(MAX([Date])) = 'Saturday' THEN 
                          DATEADD(d,-12,MAX([Date]))
                 ELSE DATEADD(d,-6,MAX([Date])) END
```

Comment: Also thank you for taking the time to answer my question. It is highly valued.