# Week Start from Monday for a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below image I am trying to start the week of "**ManufactureDate**" to every **Monday** but unable to get it the desired result.

**Query used:**

```
select distinct     dateadd(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, [ManufactureDate]),0 )sp, [ManufactureDate] 
FROM ab
```

**Current result Set:**

```
SP                           Manufacturing Date
2019-10-14 00:00:00.000  2019-10-13 00:00:00.000
2019-10-14 00:00:00.000  2019-10-14 00:00:00.000
2019-10-14 00:00:00.000  2019-10-15 00:00:00.000
2019-10-14 00:00:00.000  2019-10-16 00:00:00.000
2019-10-14 00:00:00.000  2019-10-17 00:00:00.000
2019-10-14 00:00:00.000  2019-10-18 00:00:00.000
2019-10-21 00:00:00.000  2019-10-20 00:00:00.000
```

**Desired result:**

```
Sp        Manufacturing Date
10/14/2019  10/14/2019
10/14/2019  10/15/2019
10/14/2019  10/16/2019
10/14/2019  10/17/2019
10/14/2019  10/18/2019
10/14/2019  10/20/2019
10/21/2019  10/21/2019
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: Did you actually need the image? Looks the same as the text data (which is better).

Comment: @DaleK, no  I didn't, I think I don't have that privilege to remove answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the week start date and week end date from week number in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[ManufactureDate]) + 5) % 7) * -1, [ManufactureDate]) Sp, [ManufactureDate]
FROM ab
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3af97/1).

```
Sp                  ManufactureDate
2019-10-07          2019-10-13
2019-10-14          2019-10-14
2019-10-14          2019-10-15
2019-10-14          2019-10-16
2019-10-14          2019-10-17
2019-10-14          2019-10-18
2019-10-14          2019-10-19
2019-10-14          2019-10-20
2019-10-21          2019-10-21
```