# Get week beginning date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to get the week beginning Monday's for a range of dates. I read over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number) SO post on how to do that and tried with

```
select 
    id,
    install_date, -- leave it in to check and validate manually
    cast(dateadd(day, -1*(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, install_date)-2), install_date) as DATE) as WeekStart
from someschema.sometable
```

This gives error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 32
> invalid identifier 'WEEKDAY'

How can I get the week beginning Monday for each date in `someschema.sometable.install_date`? I.e. I'd like to eventually group by weeks where weeks run Monday to Sunday and display as the Monday week beginning?

Comment: I think your link SO post is not the correct one.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim thanks for catching that, have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is about the function name (DATE_PART instead of DATEPART) but I think you should also improve the calculation:

```
with sometable as (
select 1 id, '2021-03-23'::date install_date )
select 
    id,
    install_date, -- leave it in to check and validate manually
    cast(dateadd(day, -1*(DATE_PART(WEEKDAY, install_date)-2), install_date) as DATE) as WeekStart
from sometable;
```

I would use LAST_DAY to calculate the starting of the week:

```
with sometable as (
select 1 id, '2021-03-23'::date install_date )
select 
    id,
    install_date, -- leave it in to check and validate manually
    LAST_DAY(install_date, week) - 6 as WeekStart 
from sometable;
```

LAST_DAY https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_day.html

Comment: Thanks, this runs successfully but seems to return weeks beginning on Tuesdays and not Mondays! I changed the -2 to -1 and that seems to have done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest form is to use [part_trunc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) and truncate to 'week' using [week_start](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#first-day-of-the-week) 1

```
select column1
    ,date_trunc('week', column1) as week_start
from values 
   ('2021-03-24'::date), 
   ('2021-03-15'::date);
```

gives:

```
COLUMN1     WEEK_START
2021-03-24  2021-03-22
2021-03-15  2021-03-15
```

Comment: Thanks @simeon but I preferred the syntax of LAST_DAY in Gokhan's answer

Comment: @user14328853 wow, you want the start of the week, and there is a function that does exactly that, and you prefer to the the last day of the week and then do math, because the double indirection is "simpler to understand".... I see, you are welcome to award the answer you who you like, but I really think your SQL is worse for the next person with unneeded indirection.