# start date and end date of a week sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get dates from week number in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607817/get-dates-from-week-number-in-t-sql)

Hi,

How do I get the startdate and end date for a given week number?

"select getstartdate(weeknumber)" should give the startdate of the given week.

Thanks,
Subrat

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607817/get-dates-from-week-number-in-t-sql

Comment: i want the startdate end end dtae based on 'week number' not date.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [this thread](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50624) about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Typically (on countries like Sweden for example) week one will start on a Monday, so week 1 starts on 3rd Jan in 2011. So you are going to need to specify the year as well.

See here for a list of week start days
http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2011&country=21