# SSRS 2008 R2 calulate new date from existing that's 1 year later and on Monday?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reporting

hoping someone can help.  I have an textbox on a report that I need to calculate a new date value for from another date on the report.

I need to take an existing shipping date (say 5/5/2014) and calculate a new date which is one year later but on the Monday of that week (so would be 5/4/2015) -- we only ship product on Mondays.

I know I need to use DateAdd and probably DatePart but have been unable to find the proper formula.

can anyone help?

Comment: Try `DATEPART(WK, myDate)` with `YEAR(myDate)+1` and the following question/answers should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607817/get-dates-from-a-week-number-in-t-sql

Comment: doesn't "wk" get a week number?  I need to get the date that's one year later but on the Monday of that week?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out -- thanks for all the help.  I took the idea that Gordon had, putting it in my select statement rather than trying to manipulate it in the expression area of the textbox on the report:`SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,DATEADD(YY,1,o.REQ_DATE)),0) as NewDate'

works great!  :)