# Converting YYYYWW into YYYYMM in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-conversion, week-number

Trying to retrieve `MONTH` info of the `WEEK` ,

Input data is in `YYYYWW` format, output data is `YYYYMM` format. Both datatype is `INTEGER` .

When the week spans in two consequitive months, month of Monday will be considered.

Here is the example:

| input_yyyyww | output_yyyymm |
| --- | --- |
| 202401 | 202401 |
| 202402 | 202401 |
| 202403 | 202401 |
| 202404 | 202401 |
| 202405 | 202401 |
| 202406 | 202402 |
| 202407 | 202402 |
| 202408 | 202402 |
| 202409 | 202402 |
| 202410 | 202403 |
| 202411 | 202403 |
| 202412 | 202403 |

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using data/time datatypes instead of text?

Comment: Seems like a Calendar Table would be the safest way to go.

Comment: What do you do when a week spans two months?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get first day of from YYYYWW in tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147032/how-can-i-get-first-day-of-from-yyyyww-in-tsql)

Comment: The input data comes from the source as integer. I am open to use data/time datatypes for conversion & output.

Comment: How do you handle weeks around new year? I think you should be able to find previous answers that handle various weekly things