# How to get the Start Date of the Week, if I have the Week number of the year in SSRS Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I used the following expression to get the week number of the year:

```
=DATEPART("ww", Fields!Date.Value)
```

How to get the start date of that week number in SSRS Report.[I have this in my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4n8M.png<br)

And I want it [to achieve this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz3MD.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607817/get-dates-from-a-week-number-in-t-sql

Comment: I don't want it to be in the SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression should look like this:

```
= DATEADD("d", - DATEPART(DateInterval.Weekday,Fields!Date.Value) +1,Fields!Date.Value)
```

Explanation:
From the date field, subtract the day of week number to get the first date of week