# How to find the number of remaining days in a month based off a week number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a week number, like 32, and I need get the number of days left in the month starting from this week. How can I do in SQL Server?

Comment: `@number_of_days = 7`?

Comment: I need to get the month of this weekNumber. Then i need to know the for Week number 32 remaining days of the respective month.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get dates from a week number in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607817/get-dates-from-a-week-number-in-t-sql)

Comment: you mean you need to get 7 days for that week?

Comment: You should update your question, with what you really need, and some example output. Unless a specific week only has 1 day, the days left in the month is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DATEPART ( datepart , date )` and `datepart` can be weekday, day, month or something like that..

Visit this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the first day of the week number in question. In order to do this, we need to know what year you want as well. In the example below, I use the current year. Once this is done, then we can use `DATEDIFF()` to find the days left, from the start of the week number you passed in, to the end of the month.

```
DECLARE @WeekNo int= 32
DECLARE @Year int=datepart(year,getdate())

SELECT 
    FirstDayOfWeek =  DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))
    ,LastDayOfMonth = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) + 1, 0))
    ,DaysLeftInMonth = DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0)),DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))) + 1, 0)))
```