# Get first day of week T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

How get first day of week (Monday) where week = 6 and year = 2020 I need get 10.02.2020

eg. week 1 in 2020 is  date from 06.01.2020 - 12.01.2020
week 6 in 2020 is  date from 10.02.2020 - 16.02.2020

Comment: with reference to which week?

Comment: What data are you showing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get dates from a week number in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607817/get-dates-from-a-week-number-in-t-sql)

Comment: @sveer  I'm update question.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to `SELECT` the value `10.02.2020` from the `datum` column in the table shown, or are you trying to arrive at the date `10.02.2020` using code, given only the week number and the year? Two _completely_ different questions.

Comment: This is best solved with a physical numbers/date table. Such a table is very handsome in a lot of situations...There are various examples to find, I post one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474751/5089204) myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @YEAR int = 2020;
DECLARE @WEEKSTOADD int = 6;
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT 
        DATEADD(day, 
                1 -  DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(week,@WEEKSTOADD,cast(cast(@YEAR as varchar(4)) + '0101' as date))), 
                DATEADD(week,@WEEKSTOADD,cast(cast(@YEAR as varchar(4)) + '0101' as date)))
```

Comment: Tips: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. And you may want to update your answer for modern version of SQL Server to use [`DateFromParts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: which bit would you want to update for 'modern' SQL?  Maybe create a date now available without using a string?  I want 1 to represent a Monday though.

Comment: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 2 ) % 7 + 1` shifts the starting day to Monday. Yes, you shouldn't need to convert the year to prose, concatenate a few characters and analyze the result to get a `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get the date of Monday in the week of a given date regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`:

```
Cast( DateAdd( day, - ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, Datum ) - 2 ) % 7, Datum ) as Date )
```

An example with sample data:

```
with SampleData as (
  select GetDate() - 30 as Datum
  union all
  select DateAdd( day, 1, Datum )
    from SampleData
    where Datum < GetDate() )
select Datum,
  -- 1 = Monday through 7 = Sunday.
  ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, Datum ) - 2 ) % 7 + 1 as WeekDay,
  -- Date of Monday in the week of the supplied date.
  Cast( DateAdd( day, - ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, Datum ) - 2 ) % 7, Datum ) as Date ) as Monday
  from SampleData;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per sample data you need `substring()` :

```
select t.*, substring(datnum, charindex(' ', datnum) + 1, 10) as dt
from table t
where t.week = 6;
```